# Repeating SPSS macro for different parameter values

Tags: macros, spss

Hi I'm a beginner with SPSS macros. i wonder if people can tell me if it is possible to have parameter in the if statement using macro, for example

```
DEFINE !calc_spells (procedure = !TOKENS(1)).

*** Get the file.

get file ='C:\Users\mycomputer\Documents\file.sav'.

compute proc=0.
do repeat a=op1a to op4b.

if any(substr(a,1,4), !procedure) proc=1.
end repeat.
execute.

select if proc=1.
execute.

string procedure(a4).
compute procedure=!procedure.

*** aggregate file.
aggregate outfile=* 
   /break year procedure
   /median_cost median_stay = median(cost_spell_total_net total_stay)
   /number_of_spells = n. 

save outfile=!path_output + !QUOTE(!CONCAT(!procedure, '_output.sav')).
!enddefine.

!calc_spells procedure = A021.
!calc_spells procedure = A024.
```

Basically I would like to know if this macro can be repeated for different procedure codes instead of changing the code manually each time I run? it seems my code is not working as I get no cases at all?

Comment: Your macro looks fine, If it's not giving you the expected results it may be a problem of the syntax within the macro. Please post a sample of your data so we can help find the error. Since this is an additional question you should post this as a separate question.

Comment: @Ting Yang you could also use `set mprint=on.` This will print in the log the resulting syntax from calling the macro. As eli-k pointed out, conceptually, what you want to achieve is doable, but somewhere there is an error which has to do with the specifics of your context.

Comment: @Ting Yahng: why not use `if substr(a,1,4) =  !procedure proc=1.` ? you should use the `any` function only when you want to compare against a larger list of possible values. You are only comparing against `!procedure`

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. It worked. by using the mprint=on, i knew where the error occurred. it's actually an easy fix by adding quotation marks to procedure code, eg   !calc_spells procedure = 'A021'. thanks i was a bit silly but it worked out. cheers

Answer (score 1):

To get the macro to run over a few values of `procedure`, you can use a macro loop:

```
DEFINE !calc_spells (procedureList = !cmdend).

   !do !procedure !in (!procedureList)
      ...
       [your original macro content]
      ...
   !doend

!enddefine.

!calc_spells procedureList = A021 A024 A025 A026.
```

Comment: thank you eli-l for your answer. i tried your suggested loop codes and it still doesnt work. it looks like the problem occurs in the if statement as no values were selected.     'if any(substr(a,1,4), !procedure) proc=1'  is that because the string variable cant be recognised in the if statement ? thanks

Comment: see my comment above - please post a sample of your data (you  can add it as an edit to your original post), so we can better understand what your syntax is supposed to do and where it if failing. The above loop is only meant to repeat the macro for different values, but of course doesnt fix the macro

Comment: also - to debug the macro first try to write plain syntax, writing the parameter value instead of the parameter name, and see if that works. If it doesn't, you can debug the syntax first and then build it back into a macro